# NodeJS 'Cron' Package - schedule job which runs after every 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I've to run cron job at every 20 seconds. So after did some search, I found that we need use format like this '0/20 * * * * *'. But this format not working properly. Instead of running the job after every 20 seconds, The job runs after 1 minute. Can you please let me know what I need to set here to run the job after every 20 seconds?

```
const queue = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '0/20 * * * * *', 
  onTick: function() {
    console.log('<=============Perform Job==========>',new Date());
    performActivity();
  },
  start: false,
  timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta'
});

queue.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every 20 seconds should be `*/20`:

```
cronTime: '*/20 * * * * *',
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

`"cronTime":"*/20 * * * * *"`

or

`"cronTime":"00,20,40 * * * * *"`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the "0/20", to execute every 20 seconds you should use "*/20".

Here an example based on your code:

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const queue = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '*/20 * * * * *',
      onTick: function() {
          console.log('<=============Perform Job==========>',new Date());
      },
      start: false,
      timeZone: 'Europe/Madrid'
});

queue.start();
```